# I used pip to install a module but my program responds, "No module named..." (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-idle

Yes, there are other questions like this. However, they are all about custom modules. I used pip to install a module and for some apparent reason, on the command-line only, it responds with an error. On the IDLE and Sublime/PyCharm, it works completely fine. However, running with command-prompt, like I said, gives an error. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please give us a clear example of the error in your text?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dinos\Desktop\Games\atest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pydealer as py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydealer'

Comment: Does it fail when you import other modules (for example, import os)?

Comment: OS is built in, and yes, it works. I use improved Sublime for Python, and it works fine on there. Command-Prompt is giving and error. And I don't know why. But thanks for the response! I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple Python instances, try:

Python 2:

```
pip2 install httplib2 --upgrade
```

Python 3:

```
pip3 install httplib2 --upgrade
```

To check what's installed and where, try:

```
pip list
pip2 list
pip3 list
```

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks for the response :)

Comment: It is up to date. But, it seems to be a problem on CMD and Python Command -Line. IDLE and Sublime works.

Comment: Can you please run this: ``python -m pip --version``

Comment: I just tried updating PIP on my own. It is up-to-date. But in case you want the version, here it is: 9.01

Comment: Not sure what to say... You are using windows, right?

Comment: Yup, it's alright. I will eventually find a work around. Thanks for using your time to help me. I really appreciate it! :) <3

Comment: Your welcome :). Sorry I couldn't help. I'll upvote your question in 55 minutes (once I get my 40 daily votes) to help your post gain traction

Comment: I have discovered this problem twice more. One of which was fixed, somehow. Using the module folium, on Atom was giving the same error, and using the module pandas, on Sublime. Pandas was immediately fixed after I used pip on the specific version, which was probably the cause of Anaconda(I used to use that). With that being said, I think I might have accidentally used Anaconda on that project and pip doesn't recognize a version for that.